# nltk part of speech multiple verbs

Tags: python, nltk

I have an nltk application that requires parts of speech (pos) tagging, with the principal goal of identify verbs.  Sentences that contain a comma separated sequence of verbs are common in the application.

For example:

**I run, swim, and skate in the park.**

Consider the following code:

```
import nltk
nltk.pos_tag(nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize('I run, swim, and skate in the park'))
```

which incorrectly tags **skate** and **swim** as nouns:

```
[('I', 'PRP'), ('run', 'VBP'), (',', ','), ('swim', 'NN'), (',', ','), ('and', 'CC'), ('skate', 'NN'),('in', 'IN'), ('the', 'DT'), ('park', 'NN')]
```

When in a sentence with each verb on its own, the verb is correctly tagged.

For example:

```
nltk.pos_tag(nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize('I swim in the park'))
```

produces:

```
[('I', 'PRP'), ('swim', 'VBP'), ('in', 'IN'), ('the', 'DT'), ('park', 'NN')]
```

and

```
nltk.pos_tag(nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize('I skate in the park'))
```

produces

```
[('I', 'PRP'), ('skate', 'VBP'), ('in', 'IN'), ('the', 'DT'), ('park', 'NN')]
```

What is involved in tagging **"I run, swim, and skate in the park"**, such that run, swim, and skate are all recognized as verbs?

Thanks in advance!

Brian